# Kotlin problem with deleting object in the loop

Tags: loops, kotlin

I have person objects that have a gender field
objects the person adds to the list
then I want to remove from the list people who have man

```
enum class Gender{
  woman, man
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

  data class Person(var name: String, var surname: String, var gender: Gender)

  val person1 = Person("Jan", "Kowalski", Gender.man)
  val person2 = Person("Paweł", "Pawelski", Gender.man)
  val person3 = Person("Ewa", "Miła", Gender.woman)
  val person4 = Person("Gosia", "Zemvba", Gender.woman)

  var PersonList = listOf<Person>(person1, person2, person3, person4).toMutableList()

  val listIterator2 = PersonList.iterator()
  while (listIterator2.hasNext()) {
      var tmp = listIterator2.next()
      if (tmp.gender == Gender.man) {
          println( "deleted  " + tmp)
          PersonList.remove(tmp)

      }
  }

}
```

in line       var tmp = listIterator2.next()  i have a error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:966)  
    at TmpKt.main(tmp.kt:19)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `remove` on the iterator itself, not the list.

```
  val listIterator2 = PersonList.iterator()
  while (listIterator2.hasNext()) {
      var tmp = listIterator2.next()
      if (tmp.gender == Gender.man) {
          println( "deleted  " + tmp)
          listIterator2.remove()
      }
  }
```

It is easier to use `removeAll()` than to work with the iterator directly:

```
personList.removeAll { it.gender == Gender.man }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manipulating the original list, you can produce a new list like:

```
  val personList = listOf<Person>(person1, person2, person3, person4)
  val personListUpdated = personList.filter { it.gender != Gender.man }
```

(or, as suggested by Tenfour04 above, `removeAll` or `filterNot` can also be used to invert the condition)

See this playground to try it yourself:
https://pl.kotl.in/LGkr_cobj

Answer (score 0):

***Iterators*** are not always helpful when another thread modifies the collection. I had tried many ways but then realized traversing the collection manually is much safer (backward for remove):

```
for (i in listPersons.size-1 downTo 0) {
    myList.getOrNull(i)?.apply {
       if (gender == Gender.man)
          listPersons.remove(this)
    }
}
```